# Javascript form character counter/validation for C# project

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm trying to display a counter next to the text field where users enter in data. This counter should count down from 43 for each character entered. I've tried implementing the solution for the field below, but am not sure how given I'm not using plain html for the form.

```
<div class="editor-field" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',43);">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FIELD_DESCRIPTION)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FIELD_DESCRIPTION)
    </div>
<script>
    function textCounter(field, field2, maxlimit) {
        var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
            return false;
        } else {
            countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Update:**

View

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FIELD_DESCRIPTION)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FIELD_DESCRIPTION)
    </div>
<script>
    $('#FIELD_DESCRIPTION').keydown(function () {
        var len = 43 - $(this).val().length;
        if (len > 0)
            $('#field-validation-valid').text(len);
        else
            $('#field-validation-valid').text(0);
    });

    $('#FIELD_DESCRIPTION').keydown();
```

Page Source

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        <strong><label for="FIELD_DESCRIPTION">FIELD_DESCRIPTION</label></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="FIELD_DESCRIPTION" name="FIELD_DESCRIPTION" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FIELD_DESCRIPTION" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
<script>
    $('#FIELD_DESCRIPTION').keydown(function () {
        var len = 43 - $(this).val().length;
        if (len > 0)
            $('#field-validation-valid').text(len);
        else
            $('#field-validation-valid').text(0);
    });

    $('#FIELD_DESCRIPTION').keydown();
</script>
```

**Update:** I got it working. Although it may be useful to have it restrict the user from typing once it hits 0. Not sure how I would do that.

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FIELD_DESCRIPTION)&nbsp<span id="field-validation-valid"
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FIELD_DESCRIPTION) 
    </div>
<script>
    $('#FIELD_DESCRIPTION').keydown(function () {
        var len = 43 - $(this).val().length;
        if (len > 0)
            $('#field-validation-valid').text(len + " remaining");
        else
            $('#field-validation-valid').text(0);
    });

    $('#FIELD_DESCRIPTION').keydown();
</script>
```

Comment: You may get more replies if you post the generated html along with the server side code you have already posted.

Comment: updated including page source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an excerpt of me doing the same thing for a twitter share feed.

```
// on any user input, check the text length
$("#input-field").on("paste input keydown keyup mouseup blur", function () {
    var twitCount = (140 - $("#input-field").val().length);

    //update the counter element to display 
    $("#display-counter-field").html(twitCount);

    // if the twitterCounter gets below 14 left, then add a warning class to 
    // highlight the counter 
    (twitCount < 14)
        ? $("#display-counter-field").addClass("warning")
        : $("#display-counter-field").removeClass("warning");
});

// trigger the event so that we can ensure pre-rendered data 
// respects this as well
$("#input-field").trigger('keyup');
```

Answer (score 0):

This what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/ob3vume7/

```
<div>
    <input id='inp'><span id='inp-count' />
</div>

<script>
    $('#inp').keydown(function(){
        var len = 43 - $(this).val().length;
        if(len > 0)    
            $('#inp-count').text(len);
        else
        $('#inp-count').text(0);    
    });

    $('#inp').keydown();
</script>
```

Comment: Cool! But do you need that final $('#inp').keydown(); ?

Comment: No, but this call the event and reload the span text.